# Binding source update error after updating the database accdb

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, data-binding, visual-studio-2019

I have a winform connected to .accdb file, but while creating rdlc report I found that the naming wa not correct in my accdb file(contained hyphen) and I changed it accordingly and configured the data-set query too and refreshed the connection, but still during execution the below error is coming .

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column Condition_of_DIE-7 on the DataSource.
```

Parameter name: dataMember'

And this is my master table SQL :

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Size_in_mg,
    Die_head_number,
    Inspection_Date,
    Next_Calibration_On,
    Die_size_in_microns,
    Condition_of_DIE_1,
    Condition_of_DIE_2,
    Condition_of_DIE_3,
    Condition_of_DIE_4,
    Condition_of_DIE_5,
    Condition_of_DIE_6,
    Condition_of_DIE_7,
    Observations,
    Inspector,
    Issued_to_Maintanance
FROM MSdies
```

And this is where the error is showing is my program.cs file

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new FormMsdies());
}
```

As I am very new to C# I can't understand how to correct this please help me: please refer the below images for further help:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are defined as `Condition_of_DIE_7` and so on, but the error shows clearly that somewhere in your code, you're still using a `-` instead of a `_`:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column *Condition_of_DIE-7* on the DataSource.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , as this was asked two months ago , this has now corrected , the actual problem was the columns names not updated in the dataset (query editor) and, at that time i thought only renaming in source table will automatically refresh everywhere.

Comment: Ooops... It was one of the top questions in my custom query, so I didn't notice the date LOL! Glad you were able to fix it.